# Issue with Rotating imageOverlay

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to rotate an `imageOverlay` in Leaflet as follows:

```
img = L.imageOverlay("test.jpg", [[40.712216, -74.22655], [40.773941, -74.12544]]).addTo(map);
```

Since there is no built-in function to rotate the overlay, I have transformed the image HTML Element as follows:

```
img.getElement().style.transform = "rotate(90deg)"
```

So far so good. However when I change the zoom, the image jumps to its original situation (before rotating). Any idea about this?

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#tileimage-display , in particular https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.ImageOverlay.Rotated and https://github.com/publiclab/Leaflet.DistortableImage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using regular `imageOverlay`, I installed [leaflet-imageoverlay-rotated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-imageoverlay-rotated) as well as its [type definition](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/leaflet-imageoverlay-rotated) (I am using Angular/Typescript). Then I imported the new library along with the leaflet as follows:

```
import * as L from 'Leaflet';
import 'leaflet-imageoverlay-rotated';
```

and replaced the `imageOverlay` with `imageOverlay.rotated`. Unlike the `imageOverlay`, you have to assign 3 points for each image and rotate the image by rotating those three points. [Here](https://github.com/rezanikfal/Rotate-Scale-Move-ImageOverlay) is my code for reference.